# how to read xml in Intellij idea plugin

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I develop a intellij idea plugin,I want to read `xml` file in project.How can I do that?
And I do not want import third part jar,only use intellij dom api.

Answer (score 0):

You can read xml by `XmlFile` such as:

```
XmlFile file = ...;
final XmlDocument document = file.getDocument();
if (document != null) {
    final XmlTag rootTag = document.getRootTag();
    if (rootTag != null) {
        final XmlTag foo = rootTag.findFirstSubTag("foo");
        if (foo != null) {
            final XmlTag[] bars = foo.findSubTags("bar");
            if (bars.length > 1) {
                String s = bars[1].getValue().getTrimmedText();
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and get chrildren by `XmlTag[] tags = root.getSubTags();`,get tag name and value by `root.getName(); root.getValue().getText()`

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/frameworks_and_external_apis/xml_dom_api.html?search=xml